# Why does this lead to an segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I try to put my pointer to the parameter passed it, but it leads to a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

void putPointer ( int *point, int num ) {
    point = &num;
}

int main(void) {

    int a = 42;

    int *p;
    // p = &a
    putPointer( p, a );

    printf( "%d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the time function `putPointer` returns, its argument `num` doesn't exist any more.  C uses a "pass by value" calling convention, so `num` is a *copy* of `a`.  But also: argument `point` is a *copy* of `p` in the caller, so `p` in the caller doesnt get set to point to *anything*.

Comment: Accessong a pointer to a local variable 'num' after returnibg from function is undefined behaviour

Comment: The variable `p` is not modified by the function `putPointer`, because it is passed by value, not [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm). Therefore, dereferencing `p` will result in undefined behavior, because it is an uninitialized (wild) pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Arguments in C are *copies* of what are passed, so `p` in the `main()` function remains uninitialized after `putPointer(p,a);`. Using values of uninitialized non-static local variables, which are indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Also note that you shouldn't take out pointers to non-static local variables (including function arguments) on returning from functions and must not use these pointers after returning from functions because non-static local variables are invalidated on returning.

Answer (score 2):

In `putPointer()` you try to assign `point` but `point` is a **copy** of `p`, thus `p` is left unchanged.
Since `p` is still not initialised, it could access any address and `*p` causes a seg-fault.

You could actually change `p` by expecting `int **point_ptr` as parameter, passing `&p` and performing `*point_ptr=&num;` but you would encounter another problem.
Actually, `num` will disappear as soon as the function returns, so keeping its address in `p` is incorrect: `num` does not exist anymore when using `*p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
&num
```

will be the address of num *on the stack*. You are trying dereference the stack in `printf("%d\n", *p);`.

Comment: It's worse than that.

Comment: misread it; assumed *point was being used. also nothing wrong with dereffing the stack i suppose (if you're not using it after the retn). my bad.